# Displayng attribute text in layout Text element gives error: Error in setting text

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor, layouts, dynamic-text

I am new in Python scripting. I have a geodatabase with layer Test and this layer has field Name and Text element on layout named TEname. I am trying to show selected feature attribute Name value in Text element, but I could not do it. I can print the value for selected feature, but can't show it in Text element.

Here is the code I use:

```
import arcpy


mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
TEname = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"TEXT_ELEMENT","Name")[0]

for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Test","name")
     print row

...
(u'Land plot 1',)

for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Test","name"):
    TEname.text = row

...

        TEname.text = row
```

> Runtime error Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in
>   File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects_base.py", line 89, in
>   _set return setattr(self._arc_object, attr_name, cval(val)) RuntimeError: TextElementObject: Error in setting text

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to assign the row array to the text element, but you want to grab the first (only, in this case) element from the array:

`TEname.text = row[0]`

Answer (score -2):

As per your description the text element name is "TEname". So,
`arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"TEXT_ELEMENT","Name")[0]`
in this line try to replace "Name" by "TEname".

Also
`for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Test","name"): TEname.text = row`
In this try by replacing `TEname.text = row` to `TEname.text=row.getValue("name")`

Comment: No, when using DA cursors (which everyone should be at this point), `row` is an array